# Adding data to state store for stateful processing and fault tolerance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stateful, rocksdb

I have a microservice that perform some stateful processing. The application construct a KStream from an input topic, do some stateful processing then write data into the output topic.

I will be running 3 of this applications in the same group. There are 3 parameters that I need to store in the event when the microservice goes down, the microservice that takes over can query the shared statestore and continue where the crashed service left off.

I am thinking of pushing these 3 parameters into a statestore and query the data when the other microservice takes over. From my research, I have seen a lot of example when people perform event counting using state store but that's not exactly what I want, does anyone know an example or what is the right approach for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to do 2 things:

a. the service going down have to store the parameters:
If you want to do it in a straightforward way than all you have to do is to write a message in the topic associated with the state store (the one you are reading with a `KTable`). Use the [Kafka Producer API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerapi) or a `KStream` (could be `kTable.toStream()`) to do it and that's it.

Otherwise you could create manually a state store:

```java
// take these serde as just an example
Serde<String> keySerde = Serdes.String();
Serde<String> valueSerde = Serdes.String();
KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = inMemoryKeyValueStore(stateStoreName);
streamsBuilder.addStateStore(Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(storeSupplier, keySerde, valueSerde));
```

then use it in a transformer or processor to add items to it; you'll have to declare this in the transformer/processor:

```java
// depending on the serde above you might have something else then String
private KeyValueStore<String, String> stateStore;
```

and initialize the `stateStore` variable:

```java
@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
  stateStore = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore(stateStoreName);
}
```

and later use the `stateStore` variable:

```java
@Override
public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String value) {
  // using stateStore among other actions you might take here
  stateStore.put(key, processedValue);
}
```

b. read the parameters in the service taking over:
You could do it with a Kafka consumer but with Kafka Streams you first have to make the store available; the easiest way to do it is by creating a KTable; then you have to get the queryable store name that is automatically created with the KTable; then you have to actually get access to the store; then you extract a record value from the store (i.e. a parameter value by its key).

```java
// this example is a modified copy of KTable javadocs example
final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

// Creating a KTable over the topic containing your parameters a store shall automatically be created.
//
// The serde for your MyParametersClassType could be 
// new org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde(MyParametersClassType.class) 
// though further configurations might be necessary here - e.g. setting the trusted packages for the ObjectMapper behind JsonSerde.
//
// If the parameter-value class is a String then you could use Serdes.String() instead of a MyParametersClassType serde.
final KTable paramsTable = streamsBuilder.table("parametersTopicName", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), <<your InstanceOfMyParametersClassType serde>>));

...
// see the example from KafkaStreams javadocs for more KafkaStreams related details
final KafkaStreams streams = ...;
streams.start()
...

// get the queryable store name that is automatically created with the KTable
final String queryableStoreName = paramsTable.queryableStoreName();
// get access to the store
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore view = streams.store(queryableStoreName, QueryableStoreTypes.timestampedKeyValueStore());
// extract a record value from the store
InstanceOfMyParametersClassType parameter = view.get(key);
```

Comment: Thank adrhc for reply, so just to clarify. By doing option a) that is writing these parameters into a separate Kafka topic say "param-stored", this one doesn't create a state store or anything. But in process b) when i generate a KTable from the "param-stored" topic, this will create a state store. Then I can access the stored Param normally from the ReadOnlyKeyValueStore object... I initially thought you don't need to create a separate topic to store the parameters, instead create a state store then write values into it. Then access it to rehydrate the state of the microservice taking over.

Comment: also the act of creating the KTable from the a topic means you have to read the whole topic from the beginning to rebuild the state. That will have more overhead compare to in memory access with state store within the same consumer group right?

Comment: It'll be a startup delay which depends on how much data you have in the compacted topic: at minimum you'll only have 1 record (containing an object keeping those 3 parameters) while at maximum you might have e.g. the last 1000 updates which is still almost nothing.